# How does http/ssh protocol work?

Tags: http, networking, ssh, router

When I use one of these protocols, does it directly send requests to the end device? Or does it go through the intermediate machines that route traffic like a router/switch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As application-level protocols, they simply define what data is transmitted via lower-level protocols like IP (where routing details are handled).

Comment: Okay, so if I use the http protocol, packets are sent from port 80 on my machine through port 80 on the routers and arrive at port 80 at the end device?

Comment: Close enough. The port numbers are really a kind of meta data, rather than having any "physical" meaning, so packets don't really go "through" ports on the routers, but the routers might use the port number for prioritizing packets (load balancing, etc) or even filtering.

Comment: If i block port 80 on a router, what happens? Will the packet not go through or will it find some other way?

Comment: You're asking "how does my network implement routing?" which is far too broad a question to ask here.