# In Browser SSH client

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

I had the idea for an in-browser ssh client, but i couldnt find any detailed explanation on how to write a SSH client. I tried looking it up but i couldnt find anything(Most results were about Putty or rankings of clients).

One idea would be to write an express app on the server that just executes the command it gets by the URL paramater or something else, but

1. it wouldnt be very secure i guess
2. i got curious

I think it works similarly to a websocket. First you send a normal http request or something and then you try to "upgrade" the request to a ssh tunnel

[How does http/ssh protocol work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541906/how-does-http-ssh-protocol-work) couldnt help

Edit:
Any Keywords or links to articles about how to code your own SSH Client or server would help

Thanks

Comment: ... and your question is? (Maske sure it's within the scope on stackoverflow, as documented in [help/on-topic])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just tunnel your ssh connection through Web Socket.
The problems are how you build the functionality of ssh client if you want ssh connections start from local users.
To develop the client in browser(meanwhile in a site), the most works can only be done by JavaScript.
However, because of secure problems, JavaScript has lots of limits in contrast with normal local programs.

The another way you provide that execute commands on server is surely easy to do, but the problem is : how can I trust the web application and the server as I need to provide my private information?
If I can use mature ssh technology to 100% ensure my security, how do we make people believe that the ssh web application is totally safe and willing to use it?

Comment: A very good question at the end. Living Bots is a platform where u can rent servers. After you rent one you get access to a webinterface where one option is to go to a kvm console. In a nutshell: It is a square where i can input text like "whoami" and the square will show me the response the server put out

Comment: My question is "How do i get the same" or "what technologie does living bots use to send for example 'sudo apt update' and get the response back on the website"

Comment: The first is that I don't think that to use the commands are mainly designed for interactive shell is stable and reliable.  The functions you described are mostly shell script stuffs. And why people use shell scripts because they need easy system management, which is one of the main purpose of shells.
And if we don't discuss the problems I mentioned.  The shell commands are not designed for these specific purpose(as I mentioned). You may need to use libs like OpenSSL to do what you want hard but safe and stable.